# How to construct a list in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, shacl

I have a `ttl` file that looks like this:

```
ex:Shape1
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:property ex:Property-1
    rdfs:label "Shape 1"

ex:Property-1
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:path ex:property1
    sh:in (
        "Option 1"
        "Option 2"
    ) ;
    sh:name "Property 1"

ex:property1
    a owl:DatatypeProperty
```

After loading the above data into my triple store (which contains many shapes already), what query can I use to retrieve the same data back?

This query gets everything I need except for the list. For the list it only gives a blank node.

```
PREFIX sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/#>

CONSTRUCT {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
WHERE {
  {
    bind(ex:Shape1 as ?subject)
    ex:Shape1 ?predicate ?object
  }
  UNION
  {
     ex:Shape1 sh:property ?subject .
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
  }
  UNION
  {
    ex:Shape1 sh:property/sh:path ?subject .
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
  }
}
```

Comment: see the Turtle specs how a list is internally serialized in RDF as a set of RDF triples: https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#collections

Comment: I've read that, and saw this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422197 but It is not clear to me how to construct the list when it is nested into another property.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need to query to get the same data back? Do you mean you need to get it in the same syntax and formatting?

- to get the same data in the form of triples, you can simply execute SELECT * from ?s ?p ?o and it will give you all the triples. It also depends on your triplestore.
- The standard query to fetch the items in your list would be the following:

  ```
  PREFIX sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>
  PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/#>
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  SELECT ?item
  WHERE {
    ex:Property-1 sh:in/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?item
  }
  ```

You can read more about how the list items are stored internally. This [link](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2014/04/rdf-lists-and-sparql.html) will be helpful.
You can bind the ex:Property-1 in the same way in UNION or WHERE clause in your construct query to get the desired result.

I hope it is helpful. Good luck.

Comment: This question is related to another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72521705/3727991.
I am trying to reconstruct a SHACL shape in a store with many other SHACL shapes.